# Как сделать ИИ который будет определять похожа ли картинка на ту которая указана в системе?

Tags: python-3.x, искусственный-интеллект

у меня появилась проблема как сделать ***ИИ на Python*** который будет определять схожесть картинки. Я пока не понимаю как это сделать, **даже гугл не выдал решения**.
Ну представим, есть у меня флаг Англии, и человек решил сфоткать флаг где-то на улице, и моей программе нужно проверить - **Похожа ли фотка** на **флаг Англии**. Заранее спасибо, просто предложите пример работы такого механизма)

Comment: Ну для начала изучите ИИ

Comment: Интересно, какой запрос вы делали, если гугл не выдал решение :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Серьезно? Даже Гууглили? И он так и сказал -  "Вот лично вам - никаких решений"? Не верю!

Вот, прямо с первой страницы поиска:

https://medium.com/@senior_sigan/similar-images-search-ce433491059b

https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/450120/

https://habr.com/ru/post/320720/

https://www.slideshare.net/yandex/research-41551707

https://bitworks.software/products/image-search/

http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/537.html

Подозревая, что у вас проблемы с английским, привел только русскоязычные ссылки. Пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите например руководство [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification?hl=ru)